# Spring security: public API to register new user

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a use-case where I want to `HTTP POST` a `userName` as JSON to my service, and the service should then register a new user (with a given `userName` and an auto-generated password).

**JSON**

```
{
"userName": "Sia"
}
```

I am using `Spring Security`, and the problem I am facing is that:

Whenever I try to `HTTP POST` a `userName`, the service already asks for authentication (username and password). This is not why I want. I want a registration API to be completely public. Meaning that everyone (unauthorized) can `HTTP POST` a new username and thus "open the account".

I am not sure how I could achieve the wanted behaviour. Parts of the service should be public (like creating a new user as described above), and some parts should indeed require authentication (of the users that are created in the described public `POST` procedure). Any advice?

**pom.xml**

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Autowired
private UserService service;    

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user")
public void register(@PathVariable String userName) {
    System.err.println("!!!!!!!!!!!"); // this line never gets executed

    service.save(userName);
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
public void save(String userName) {     
    String password = pwGenerator.generate();       
    repository.save(new User(userName, password));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to permit `/user` POST request through spring security.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user") 
               .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a URL that is permitte by all in your security configuration:

```
.antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
```

In case you face issues with CSRF protection you can deactivate it with

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Build the request matcher for CSFR protection
    RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

        // Always allow the HTTP GET method

        // Disable CSFR protection on the following urls:
        private AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = {
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user") };

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {

            if (request.getMethod().matches(GET_METHOD_REGEX))
                return false;

            for (AntPathRequestMatcher rm : requestMatchers) {
                if (rm.matches(request)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } // method matches

    }; // new RequestMatcher
```

And use the above in the http configuration.

```
http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
```

Comment: Hmm, where should that method be? What module is that a part of?

Comment: The configuration of your Spring security where you load the username and passwords

Comment: Well, I never really load them... it is a runtime service, I just have a repository with all the users being populated exclusively from HTTP POST. I guess I should add some kind of configuration class with this method?

Comment: And btw. GET_METHOD_REGEX, well the getMethod() should return the type of method already by it's own (ie GET or POST), do I need to additionally check for some special regex?

Comment: Yes like the answer below. Just keep in mind the csrf. The post is what matters the get for all Get requests